# Facing issue with Twitter API due to LIMITs

Tags: php, twitter

I am using Twitter API to fetch tweets based on some hash tag. This is a CRON job which runs every 1 minute. In each run of CRON job, there are lots of requests sent to twitter to fetch tweets containing some hash tag (these hash tags are saved into database and can be added more from our application. each time these hash tags are fetched from database and based on these hash tags requests are being made to twitter API.)

Now the issue is when number of requests reached the limit for that window (15 minutes window), the API sends error with message “Rate LIMIT exceed”. And for that window, no requests could be possible.

I don’t want to let it stop working. So is there any other APIs for this type of real time Application which we can use? Or any other solution is there?

Comment: It does not make any sense to run your job every minute. Probably, your current job will take more than one minute, and another job will start before first one ends. Increase the interval between jobs. Make it every one hour.

Comment: I cannot increase interval to 1 hour, but yes I can do it for 5 min. but still same issue.. is there any other API to do this, what about streaming API of twitter? I don't have much knowledge about it...